# Geometry Nodes - a curve line between each pair of points at index and index + 1

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have a node setup as in the screen below. I try to create a curve line between every two instances (at index and index+1) given by the "Instance on points" node. When I try to do it for the specific two indices - it works as expected, but once I connect the "Index" node, the Sample at Index node output, become a function, and Quadratic Bezier does not accept it's result anymore. I understand why it's happening and this is indeed expected, but I have no idea how to achieve my goal - is it even possible?
I use Blender 3.5.0

Current:
[image]

Wanted (but for every two instance, not just first ones):[image]

Comment: The Quadratic-Bezier's input sockets are always round when you instance it. They are not diamond-shaped. This means that they generate geometry objectwise (once) not instance-wise (per point). Try instancing a curve with two points on each position, realize them and continue with that real geometry.

Comment: look at this answer, retry solving your issues, then update your question. https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/291514/165102

Comment: @shmuel I did understand the "no loop" thing, however I hoped maybe I just don't see some "magic" combination of Duplicate Elements and Set Position that I just can't figure out or something like that.  I don't know exactly - if I knew I wouldn't ask :) but based on the link you gave, basically - the thing I want is impossible right? I just need to try different approach like for example in the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if something more concise or shorter can be done. But that may be a solution.

[image]

Here is the result from six mesh points:

[image]

The group input has three slots:

- the mesh line
- the resolution for each quadratic line
- a Z delta for the bottom part of the quadratic line

Top part:

[image]

From the input geometry, it creates a mesh line that as a vertex count that is the resolution multiplied by the vertex amount (one resolution amount for each interval + one for the last vertex).

The "set position" is calculated below.

Second part:

[image]

This is calculating the vertex position from the quadratic formula given three points.

The formula (parametric on "t") is the following:

```
P(t) = P0*t^2 + P1*2*t*(1-t) + P2*(1-t)^2
```

Next, calculating the 3 points we need for each segment of the initial shape/mesh:

[image]

which cuts the indices into chunks that are at the resolution size. Then takes mesh points and their middle lowered on Z by the input parameter.

[image]

PS: I would be very interested to see a solution that uses only three points on a bezier curve with the good tuning of the handles to have the same result. Is it possible? What is the math?

Comment: it's not exactly what I wanted, but it looks good - as mentioned in the comment above, the thing that I want, is most likely impossible at the moment. I'll mark your answer

Comment: you may encounter index order issues. To avoid that prefer starting from (for instance) a poly line instead of a mesh (as I did in the example above).

Comment: @MattNomatter if you're focused on the implementation detail - connecting fields to circular fields - yes, it's impossible. If there's a particular result you want to achieve which lemon's solution doesn't - you have to explain it, because he solves the problem exactly as I understood it.